# create-react-app Project reloading when local server generates files

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, matplotlib, flask

I am building a developer tool which allows the user to query device data for a given time window from a DB, generates plots of the data using matplotlib, saves them to local files, and renders them on a webpage. I've used create-react-app for the frontend and a Flask backend, both of which are run locally. The issue is that when the backend creates a new directory for the plots, the react app reloads before the plots are even generated, and I get a 'Request aborted' error on the browser. The strangest thing is that it does not break on the first request, and embeds all the plots correctly. It breaks only on subsequent requests. How do I get around this?

Here's the plotter code that creates the directory and saves files:

```
fig_latest = plt.figure()
ax_latest = fig_latest.add_subplot(projection='3d')
plot_latest = ax_latest.bar3d(x, y, bottom, width, depth, latest_height, color='c')

fig_ani= plt.figure()
ax_ani = fig_ani.add_subplot(projection='3d')
def update_plot(frame, data):
        for bar in ax_ani.collections:
            ax_ani.collections.pop()
        frame_data = data[frame].to_numpy().astype(np.int16)
        height = frame_data.ravel()
        print(f'Frame: {int(frame)}')
        timestamp = time.strftime('%d %b %Y, %I:%M:%S %p', time.localtime(int(frame/1000)))
        for text in ax_ani.texts:
            text.set_visible(False)
        ax_ani.text2D(0.6, 1, f'Time: {timestamp}', transform=ax_ani.transAxes)
        return [ax_ani.bar3d(x, y, bottom, width, depth, height, color='c')]
bar_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig_ani, update_plot, frames=row_data.keys(), fargs=(row_data,), interval=750)

os.mkdir(path_name)
mpeg_writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=2)
bar_ani.save(os.path.join(path_name, 'animation.mp4'), writer=mpeg_writer)
fig_latest.savefig(os.path.join(path_name, 'latest.png'))
```

The app reloads right after `os.makedir` is called.

Flask backend:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import plotter
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:3001"}})

@app.route('/plots', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost')
def respond():
    data = request.json
    device_id = data['deviceId']
    start_time = data['startTime']
    end_time = data['endTime']
    print(f'{device_id}, {start_time}, {end_time}')
    return plotter.build_plots(device_id, start_time, end_time)
```

Code for the POST request on the frontend:

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/plots'
const requestPlot = (deviceId, startTime, endTime) => {
  const plotRequest = {
    deviceId,
    startTime,
    endTime
  }
  console.log(plotRequest)
  return axios
         .post(baseUrl, plotRequest)
         .then(response => {
           console.log('RECEIVED RESPONSE!')
           return response.data
         })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are running your frontend application in "development" mode via "npm start" command. Since webpack is watching all file changes and reloads frontend on each file editied or created. One way to fix it - is to run "npm build" command and setup nginx or run your frontend with SimpleHTTP server of python in "dist" directory